# Error .. Failed to load PDF document (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs

I am having issue while displaying pdf from data URI. I have tried this solution after looking a lot in google, do you guys think I have made any mistake ?

This is the link for codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/pdf-view-reactjs-4ygjc

Comment: I get a message "This page has been blocked by Chrome" when I hover over code preview. Seems like the browser might be blocking the content inside your iFrame.

Comment: @MMH looks like this is different thing, when we preview the page in new window we see this error. https://4ygjc.csb.app/